# How to solve this implicit integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Variable $u$ is a function of variable $t$. I am given the double derivative of $u$ with respect to $t$ (i.e. $\ddot{u} = \frac{d^2 u}{dt^2}$). I now want to integrate $\ddot{u}$ with respect to $u$. 
\begin{equation}
\int \ddot{u} du
\end{equation}
The answer is given as $\frac{\dot{u}^2}{2}$. How do I do this integration?

Comment: Got it. Thanks Jacky!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
(\dot u^2)' = 2\dot u \ddot u 
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\int \ddot u du = \int \ddot u \dot u\ dx = \frac{1}{2}\int (\dot u^2)' = \frac{1}{2} \dot u^2.  
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing ahead of time that $(\dot{u}^2)^\prime = 2\dot{u}\ddot{u}$, you can still arrive at the correct solution using substitution.

First, by definition, $\frac{du}{dx} = \dot{u}$, so $\int \ddot{u}du = \int \ddot{u}\dot{u}dx$. Then, let $s = \dot{u}$, so $\frac{ds}{dx} = \ddot{u}\dot{u}$ by implicit differentiation. Thus, the integral becomes $\int sds = \frac{1}{2}s^2 = \frac{1}{2}\dot{u}^2$.

Note that the intuition for using $s = \dot{u}$ is the same as any other substitution -- you can see that $\dot{u}$ is in the integrand and it's derivative $\ddot{u}$ is in the numerator of the integrand.